# Get xyz coordinate on surface of a sphere

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, spheres

I'm no mathematician so please take that into account in replies.

Lets say we have a sphere located at `0, 0, 0,`

The radius is 0.5m

We want the surface origin to be `x=0, y=0.5, z=0`

I want to be able to add an angle in degrees to the x/y plane and add an angle in degrees to the z-plane and get back the xyz coordinate.

For example starting at the origin `x=0, y=0.5, z=0` + 90 degrees(xy) = `x=0.5, y=0, z=0` adding 90 degree to the z gives the coordinate `x=0, y=0, z=0.5`.

What is the equation for translating this?

In Python I've tried the following but it is not delivering the desired result:

```
def location_on_sphere(radius, rotation_horizontal, rotation_vertical):

    elevation = radians(rotation_vertical)
    alpha = radians(rotation_horizontal)
    r = radius

    x = r * cos(elevation) * sin(alpha)
    y = r * cos(elevation) * cos(alpha)
    z = r * sin(elevation)
    print(str(x) + ' ' + str(y) + ' ' + str(z))

location_on_sphere(radius=0.5, rotation_horizontal=0, rotation_vertical=0)
```

Edit: I've updated the above code relative to comments

Results:

`location_on_sphere(radius=0.5, rotation_horizontal=0, rotation_vertical=0)` : `x=0.0 y=0.5 z=0.0` Correct

`location_on_sphere(radius=0.5, rotation_horizontal=90, rotation_vertical=0)` : `x=0.5 y=3.061616997868383e-17 z=0.0` Nearly correct, correct would be `x=0.5, y=0, z=0`, give the power to -17 then the 3.06... is just a residue, so I think this now works? I'll run some tests.

Comment: What is '' surface origin ''? x=0.5, y=1.0, z=0 is not on the sphere of radius 0.5

Comment: corrected to x=0, y=0.5, z=0 - essentially the coordinate at the front of the sphere assuming a flat xy plane with y being front to back and x being left to right

Comment: $x,y,z$ are used for cartesian coordinates while $\rho, \phi, \theta$ are used for spherical coordinates. It seems that you are mixing both as you express $x,y,z$ in degrees while degrees is only for angles. You should take a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_common_coordinate_transformations#To_Cartesian_coordinates_2

Comment: You could get at least half the solution if you exchange the formulas for $y$ and $z$. That is, in your formulation the "up" direction seems to be the $y$ coordinate, if you identify "surface origin" with "north pole".

Comment: I'm wanting to get cartesian coordinates for a location on the sphere. In the cartesian coordinates z is up/down, x is left/right, y is front back (x and y can be swapped around if that makes things easier). Feeding in an angle of rotation horizontal plane and/or vertical plane. Imagine a 3D grid or a cube with a sphere inside it, the sphere with a marked location. As the sphere rotates by a horizontal/vertical angle the point moves in cartesian space to a new xyz location, it is the xyz location I'm trying to calculate based on the angular movement.

Comment: The `degrees()` calls after `x=`, `y=` and `z=` seem wrong and unnecessary. In all the $3$ right-hand sides, `radius` multiplied by `sin` or `cos` results are already lengths, not angles.

Comment: Note that you did not get back the original coordinates. You went from $(0,0.5,0)$ to $(0.5,0,0)$ and then to $(0,0,0.5)$ The last point is along $z$ axis, not along $y$. Or do you want the new $x,y,z$ coordinates? It's not clear

Comment: @Andrei that was the idea, a new location after moving through the horizontal plane and then through the vertical plane. Clearly this is a trickier question than I first thought.

Comment: In addition to removing the calls to `degrees` (which are going to make all your coordinates too large by a factor of about $57.3$) I would change `sin(polar)` to `cos(polar)` in the formula for `x`. The use of `sin(polar)` to calculate `z` is correct, but that should be the only place that particular function call occurs.

Answer (score 2):

After reading your question and comments, the choices of directions and variable names are still ambiguous to me. In particular, the variables `alpha` and `polar` only appear in code but not defined elsewhere, and `alpha` is also not defined in your [Math Insight "solution"](https://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates#:%7E:text=Since%20r%3D%CF%81sin%CF%95,%CE%B8z%3D%CF%81cos%CF%95) (mentioned in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545722/get-xyz-coordinate-on-surface-of-a-sphere#comment9559269_4545749)).

The following is my interpretation, and is different from the existing answer.

Consider the first rotation in your question: to rotate point $(x=0, y=r, z=0)$ on the $xy$-plane by an azimuthal angle $\alpha$. Keeping the $z$-coordinate fixed, this is a rotation on a 2D polar coordinate system. But less conventionally, here a positive $\alpha$ is when rotating from the positive $y$-direction towards the positive $x$-direction, according to your example. The intermediate result is

$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix {x'\\y'\\z'} &=
\pmatrix{\cos \alpha &\sin \alpha & 0\\-\sin \alpha & \cos \alpha & 0\\0&0&1}\pmatrix{0\\r\\0} = \pmatrix{r\sin\alpha\\r\cos\alpha\\0}
\end{align*}$$

(Check by putting $r=0.5$ and $\alpha = +90^\circ$, as in [your comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4545722/get-xyz-coordinate-on-surface-of-a-sphere#comment9559303_4545749).)

Then the second rotation in your question: to rotate the intermediate point "to the $z$-plane", which is not well-defined to me. I interpret this as to "add" an elevation angle (or latitude angle) to the intermediate point on the $xy$-plane, towards the positive $z$-direction. But note that [the elevation angle is $90^\circ$ minus the polar angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Definition), and I will not call the elevation angle `polar` below.

Considering the new $x$- and $y$-coordinates only, radially the final point is scaled by $\cos (\text{elevation})$. The new $z$-coordinate becomes $r\sin(\text{elevation})$ after rotation.

$$\begin{align*}
\pmatrix {x\\y\\z} &=
\pmatrix{r\cos(\text{elevation})\sin\alpha\\r\cos(\text{elevation})\cos\alpha\\r\sin(\text{elevation})}
\end{align*}$$

(Check by putting $r=0.5$, $\alpha = +90^\circ$, $\text{elevation}=+90^\circ$, as in your question.)

Comment: @Spatial Digger This agrees with my interpretation of how you tried to define your angles. You can translate the "matrix" format of the answer directly into code by reading it line by line: for example, set $x$ to $r\cos(\text{elevation})\sin\alpha.$ Note that this says to swap `sin(alpha)` and `cos(alpha)` in your code; the way you had it is how people rotate when they start on the $x$ axis. Of course the elevation and $\alpha$ must be in radians, as you already know.

Comment: @DavidK The ambiguous part is that I am not sure how OP define their variables, and so I am not sure how close my interpretation is. I was mostly matching OP's examples, and so I had to swap to `x = ... * sin(alpha)` and `y = ... * cos(alpha)` to match the starting point (on the $y$-axis) and rotation direction.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, `alpha` is intended as the rotation in the horizontal plane, whereas `polar` is intended as the vertical rotation. Initially give in degrees, this will be converted to radians for implementation.

Answer (score 0):

The first operation is a rotation about the $z$ axis, the second about the $y$ axis. Set the angles as $α=toradians(alpha)$ and $beta=toradians(polar)$. In total the chain of operations assembles as
$$
\pmatrix{x\\y\\z}
=
R_y(alpha)R_z(polar)\pmatrix{0\\r\\0}\\
=\pmatrix{\cosα&0&\sinα\\0&1&0\\\sinα&0&\cosα}
\pmatrix{\cosβ&-\sinβ&0\\\sinβ&\cosβ&0\\0&0&1}
\pmatrix{0\\r\\0}\\
=\pmatrix{\cosα&0&\sinα\\0&1&0\\\sinα&0&\cosα}
\pmatrix{-r\sinβ\\r\cosβ\\0}\\
=\pmatrix{-r\cosα\sinβ\\r\cosβ\\-r\sinα\sinβ}\\
$$

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but as I stated in the OP 'I'm no mathematician'. I'm trying to understand this so I can get closer to understanding the solution https://mathinsight.org/spherical_coordinates#:~:text=Since%20r%3D%CF%81sin%CF%95,%CE%B8z%3D%CF%81cos%CF%95. While I'm sure the above is perfectly logical from a mathematics perspective I would greatly appreciate it if you could write it in more simple notation `x = Ry(alpha)*Rz(polar)` etc. e.g. something more suitable for programming into python

Comment: This is not easy, there are several ways to define coordinates on the sphere or generally the orientation of a rigid body in space. Your source starts with a point along the $x$ axis, $(r,0,0)^T$, and rotates it then first about the y axis to get the correct height and then around the $z$ axis to get the correct direction in the $xy$ plane. This then results in the standard polar coordinates.

Comment: The rotation matrices $R_x$, $R_y$, $R_z$ are matrices, another name is Givens rotations, so they apply to all coordinates simultaneously. The degree vs. radians conversion is applied to the angles, not the resulting coordinates.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to try and explain this, perhaps a worked example would help? So, we start at the origin point on the sphere in cartesian coordinates we are at 0, 0.5, 0. we rotate the horizonal plane +90 degrees, we are now at 0.5, 0, 0 in cartesian coordinates. So by only supplying the radius of the sphere (0.5) the origin location, and the angle of horizontal rotation, how do we get to the answer 0.5, 0, 0 ? Alpha can = radians(alpha) and Beta can = radians(polar). In this case radians(alpha) = radians(90) = 1.57

Comment: Usually this is a rotation by $-90°$ or $90°$ clockwise. With the first rotation and $90°$ you have to be careful, there is this thing called "gimbal lock". It is perhaps easier to understand the reverse process, starting with any point $(x,y,z)^T$, the first rotation could be a rotation in the $yz$ coordinates, that is, about the $x$ axis, to get a new point with $z$ coordinate zero. Then followed by a rotation in the $xy$ coordinates about the $z$ axis to also get the $x$ coordinate to zero. In the other direction the sequence of operations also gets reversed.